# How do I use parens '()' in a find command when building options from array?

Tags: bash, find

I have a function that looks like this. I have stripped error handling, and the commands outside the function are to make sure I have something to look for in the example.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

findfiles() {
  local path=$1
  local mtime=$2
  local prunedirs=$3

  local -a fopts
  fopts+=("$path")

  [[ -n $prunedirs ]] && {
    fopts+=('-type' 'd')
    fopts+=('(' '-path')
    fopts+=("${prunedirs// / -o -path }")
    fopts+=(')' '-prune' '-o')
  }

  fopts+=('-type' 'f')
  fopts+=('-writable')
  fopts+=('-mtime' "+$mtime")

  [[ -n $prunedirs ]] && fopts+=('-print')

  echo "find ${fopts[*]}"
  find "${fopts[@]}"
}

mkdir -p dir1/{dir2,dir3}
touch dir1/5daysago.txt -mt "$(date -d 'now - 5 days' +%Y%m%d%H%M)"
touch dir1/dir2/6daysago.txt -mt "$(date -d 'now - 6 days' +%Y%m%d%H%M)"
touch dir1/dir3/10daysago.txt -mt "$(date -d 'now - 10 days' +%Y%m%d%H%M)"

echo '---------------------------------------------'
findfiles dir1 4
echo '---------------------------------------------'
findfiles dir1 4 'dir1/dir2'
echo '---------------------------------------------'
findfiles dir1 4 "dir1/dir2 dir1/dir3"
```

This outputs the following:

```
---------------------------------------------
find dir1 -type f -writable -mtime +4
dir1/dir2/6daysago.txt
dir1/dir3/10daysago.txt
dir1/5daysago.txt
---------------------------------------------
find dir1 -type d ( -path dir1/dir2 ) -prune -o -type f -writable -mtime +4 -print
dir1/dir3/10daysago.txt
dir1/5daysago.txt
---------------------------------------------
find dir1 -type d ( -path dir1/dir2 -o -path dir1/dir3 ) -prune -o -type f -writable -mtime +4 -print
dir1/dir2/6daysago.txt
dir1/dir3/10daysago.txt
dir1/5daysago.txt
```

Notice that the third attempt does *not* prune the directories. If I copy and paste the find (escaping the parens) it works correctly.

```
$ find dir1 -type d \( -path dir1/dir2 -o -path dir1/dir3 \) -prune -o -type f -writable -mtime +4 -print
dir1/5daysago.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `echo "find ${fopts[*]}"`, can you do `printf '%q ' find "${fopts[@]}"; echo;` to accurately and unambiguously show the contents of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-o` and the `-path` primary as separate array elements. Each directory to prune should be passed as a separate argument, not a single space-separated string.

```
findfiles() {
  local path=$1
  local mtime=$2
  shift 2
  n=$#  # Remember for later

  local -a fopts
  fopts+=("$path")

  if (( $# > 0 )); then
    fopts+=(-type d '(')
    while (( $# > 1 )); do
        fopts+=(-path "$1" -o)
        shift
    done
    fopts+=(-path $1 ')' -prune -o)
  fi

  fopts+=('-type' 'f')
  fopts+=('-writable')
  fopts+=('-mtime' "+$mtime")

  # Now it's later
  ((n > 0)) && fopts+=('-print')

  echo "find ${fopts[*]}"
  find "${fopts[@]}"
}

findfiles dir1 4 "dir1/dir2" "dir1/dir3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo "find ${fopts[*]}"` to `declare -p fopts` to unambiguously print the options. Doing so will show that the `-o -path` part is being added as a single word:

```
$ declare -p fopts
declare -a fopts=(
    [0]="dir1" [1]="-type" [2]="d" [3]="(" [4]="-path"
    [5]="dir1/dir2 -o -path dir1/dir3" [6]=")" [7]="-prune" [8]="-o" [9]="-type" [10]="f" 
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [11]="-writable" [12]="-mtime" [13]="+4" [14]="-print"
)
```

To fix it you'll want to add each directory to prune to the array individually, something like:

```
local prunedirs=("${@:3}")

...

fopts+=(-type d '(' -false)
for dir in "${prunedirs[@]}"; do
  fopts+=(-o -path "$dir")
done
fopts+=(')' -prune -o)
```

I've switched `prunedirs` to an array so it can handle directory names with whitespace.

It starts with an initial `-false` check so there's no need to check if `prunedirs` is empty. If it's empty the whole thing is still added but since it just says `-type d '(' -false ')' -prune -o` it's a no-op.

Also, notice you don't have to quote every single argument. It's fine to write `-type d` and such unquoted, the same as you would if you typed them at the command line. Only `'('` and `')'` need single quotes.